# Assign each user to user's own plugin

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-user-plugin

I want each users to have their own database prefix so i come up with one user one plugin, so when one user login only one specific plugin activated

`user a with database prefix  user_a_  and  user b with prefix user_b_  and so on for each user`

So base on @chiragpatel opinion.. this will not work..

UPDATED

so how about creating one single login page and redirect users to user's own octobercms installation.. can i do this.. and each user october installation can only be reach from the single login page.. can this happen?

Comment: one user one plugin means in the backend you want to define different plugins for different users?

Comment: Yes.. that is what come up in my mind.. possible or not?

Comment: So how many users you have?  limited ?

Comment: Maybe around 75 - 100 users.. and each user has around 25 tables

Comment: Or is it possible to have unlimited users with this method

Comment: No this will not work I think. You have 25 tables and if you will create 100 users so at last, you will have 2500 tables so it loads heavily at the end.

Comment: Each users have 25 fields or tables?

Comment: So do you any idea to solve this.. or maybe each user has different database.. or each user has fresh install octobercms..

Comment: Is it still.heavy load when one user login only one plugin activated..

Comment: 25 tables not fields

Comment: Based on my opinion, this will not work because at the end you have 2500 tables if count 100 users. First problem will be handling database.

Comment: Oo.. ok.. i come up with another idea.. will update my question..

Comment: what you mean by redirect user's own octobercms installation ? octobercms will already be installed once in the system. What I guess, you want something like subdomain for each user. Can we install multiple octobercms within already installed OctoberCMS ?  probably not..u need to change your way to achieve the things which you want to do i suppose.

Comment: The idea is to make a simple monitoring system for superadmin to access all users data and setting.. is there a way that can done with october

Comment: No need for multiple octobercms Installations, what happens when you roll updates? update 100 codebase? It should be one codebase and multiple tenants databases..

Comment: So multiple tenant database is solution for me